# bottom view is out of screen, how do i fix it

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

I'm currently building a chat room layout, the layout showing properly on android studio but it looks different when running in real devices. Any advice on how do i fix the out of screen problem?

Currently using constraintlayout for the chat room layout, tried using relativelayout and the problem still persist.

Here is the xml layout for the chat room:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:ignote="MergeRootFrame">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_private_chat"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/messages"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/enter_messages"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            tools:listitem="@layout/animal_list_item" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/enter_messages"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/messages"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Send"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/enter_messages"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/enter_messages"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/enter_messages" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</layout>
```

Here is the screenshot for the layout:

[Layout in Android Studio preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjSXo.png)

[Layout running in real devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcGlR.png)

/** UPDATE **/
But when the keyboard is up and i focused out after typing, the layout become normal again

Comment: is this an activiy or fragment?

Comment: @MohitDholakia it is fragment

Comment: can you please provide your container's layout XML?

Comment: @MohitDholakia for the chat fragment?

Comment: are you adding a minus margin to your container layout?

Comment: @MohitDholakia no i didnt add negative margin

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem to attach the layout in activity. Is it device specific? I think you should add the activity layout to figure it out besides this fragment layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I run this xml at my own and it looks ok, on preview, on emulators and on real device, but I guess if you are using this layout as fragment or any other include layout `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` may lead to such an issue.

Comment: oh my, thanks a lot! It worked ^^ i used android:fitsSystemWindows on my previous screen because i am using collapsing layout with tab layout

Answer (score 0):

I used `RelativeLayout` and put the `EditText` and `Button` in a single `RelativeLayout`. Then aligned them to the bottom of its parent layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_private_chat"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/messages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/text_input_wrapper"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/animal_list_item" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/enter_messages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/enter_messages"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Send"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hi @surianto, it did work but once the keyboard goes down, the margin bottom will increase again

Comment: which margin bottom are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

try to delete bias

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:ignote="MergeRootFrame">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_private_chat"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/messages"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/enter_messages"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        tools:listitem="@layout/animal_list_item" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enter_messages"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/messages"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Send"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/enter_messages"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/enter_messages"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/enter_messages" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```